# Dynamic CREATE TABLE command creates only "general" column data type (Excel connection)

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, ssis, oledb, openrowset

I want to export all the tables in a DB to Excel files. The process should be dynamic, as the tables in the DB may vary.

The current process is using SSIS as follows:

1. Generate a `CREATE TABLE` string.
2. Use that string in an `Execute Sql` Task with Excel CM, which creates an Excel file.
3. Generate an `INSERT INTO OPENROWSET... SELECT FROM ...` command string.
4. Use this string in an `Execute Sql` Task with an SQL SERVER CM.

The problem is that the created excel file column types are all "general", even though my script says otherwise.

An example `CREATE TABLE` script:

```
CREATE TABLE `CONTACT1`
(
    [ACCOUNTNO] LongText,
    [COMPANY]   LongText,
    [CREATEON]  datetime,
    [CREATEAT]  LongText,
)
```

"playing" with the data types doesn't help. For example, using `VARCHAR(1000)` instead of `LongText`, etc.

I've tried generating both `xlsx` and `xls` files.

This problem prevents me from Inserting data later on with an `*INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(...) SELECT FROM ...*` command. An example `INSERT INTO` script:

```
INSERT INTO  OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=c:\\junk    \\accountnoWithNoApps.xlsx;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"',
'SELECT [accountno], [COMPANY], [CREATEON], [CREATEAT] FROM [CONTACT1$]')
SELECT [accountno], [COMPANY], [CREATEON], [CREATEAT] FROM CONTACT1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps these links will help (in general, it seems there's no real solution, rather workarounds)

- [SQL Server 2005 OPENROWSET insert into Excel - text to number formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349946/sql-server-2005-openrowset-insert-into-excel-text-to-number-formatting)
- [Export To Excel With Column Formatting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/36b24a60-1e0b-401c-9978-bd8570423fc7)
- [Using OpenRowSet and FormatFile option](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/1714f86b-6742-491e-913e-e15273f86d80)
- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic255083-8-1.aspx

Comment: Ok. I had used the EPPlus .NET library and created an Excel file with properly formatted columns. 

I tried to use the OPENROWSET command again, on the proper file, and it seems that the problem is with the OPENROWSET command. I cant export text field with more the 255 characters.

Any idea about how to overcome this without adding a dummy row ?

Comment: I've used VB.NET for the excel file creation. Thanks.